# Emptying WPF datagrid in codebehind

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

In WPF, I am using the DataGrid from WPF toolkit.Can anyone tell me how can i empty the data in the datagrid in codebehind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set/reset the "ItemsSource" of the datagrid.